# Tree postorder traversal in python

Tags: python, json, tree

I am trying to build a logic to add points from leaves to the paernt by adding 10% of points as reward to the parent from the sum of child node points , here in this example extra points for b have to be 6 so total b points have to be 56 , similarly for node a it should be 111.6 (100+11.6)` . I am using bigtree but fine to use some other libraries also.

```
from bigtree import nested_dict_to_tree, print_tree

path_dict = {
   "name": "a",
   "points": 100,
   "children": [
      {
         "name": "b",
         "points": 50,
         "children": [
            {"name": "d", "points": 40},
            {"name": "e", "points": 20},
         ],
      },
      {"name": "c", "points": 60},
   ],
}
root = nested_dict_to_tree(path_dict)

print_tree(root, attr_list=["points"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to define a custom `Node` class that performs the recursive computation and stores it as another class attribute `points_sum` (without changing the original `points` attribute).

Source: [bigtree Documentation on extending Nodes](https://bigtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/others/tips.html#extending-nodes)

```
from bigtree import Node, print_tree, nested_dict_to_tree


class PointNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, name: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)

    @property
    def points_sum(self):
        if self.is_leaf:
            return self.points
        return self.points + 0.1 * sum([child.points_sum for child in self.children])


# Your provided code
path_dict = {
   "name": "a",
   "points": 100,
   "children": [
      {
         "name": "b",
         "points": 50,
         "children": [
            {"name": "d", "points": 40},
            {"name": "e", "points": 20},
         ],
      },
      {"name": "c", "points": 60},
   ],
}
root = nested_dict_to_tree(path_dict, node_type=PointNode)

print_tree(root, attr_list=["points", "points_sum"])
```

This will result in the output

```
a [points=100, points_sum=111.6]
├── b [points=50, points_sum=56.0]
│   ├── d [points=40, points_sum=40]
│   └── e [points=20, points_sum=20]
└── c [points=60, points_sum=60]
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `bigtree` :)